# library not found for.....?

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, xcode

i added new framework(3rd party) and build.

Unfortunately, since the execution was not.

How do I solve this problem?
The whole four nights were spent.:(

```
Ld /Users/hansehee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBaseballManager-dbrtdyfdzzunktexlyibuzjbftoy/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/iBaseballManager.app/iBaseballManager normal armv7s
    cd /DevLibs/BaseballManager_KOR/iBaseballManager
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -L/Users/hansehee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBaseballManager-dbrtdyfdzzunktexlyibuzjbftoy/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos -L/DevLibs/BaseballManager_KOR/iBaseballManager/Classes/BaseballManager/kakaoUtil/kakao-ios-sdk -F/Users/hansehee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBaseballManager-dbrtdyfdzzunktexlyibuzjbftoy/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos -filelist /Users/hansehee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBaseballManager-dbrtdyfdzzunktexlyibuzjbftoy/Build/Intermediates/iBaseballManager.build/Distribution-iphoneos/iBaseballManager_Device.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/iBaseballManager.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreData -weak_framework AdSupport -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreTelephony -framework Security -lzlib -lstdc++ -lCxImage -lj2k -ljasper -lkakao-ios-sdk-i386-armv7-armv7s -ljbig -ljpeg -lpng -ltiff -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -liClet -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/hansehee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBaseballManager-dbrtdyfdzzunktexlyibuzjbftoy/Build/Intermediates/iBaseballManager.build/Distribution-iphoneos/iBaseballManager_Device.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/iBaseballManager_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/hansehee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBaseballManager-dbrtdyfdzzunktexlyibuzjbftoy/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/iBaseballManager.app/iBaseballManager
```

**ld: library not found for -lzlib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: What kind of 3rd party is that ? Is it just source code or library / framework ?

Comment: can you link the framework and show how you implement it

Comment: i just add this file (libkakao-ios-sdk-i386-armv7-armv7s.a)and build....it's a private file. so i can't show you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed `-all_load` to `-force_load`

Comment: What are you talking about? How did you find this solution...?

Comment: Where you will change that. I didn't find that any where

Comment: fist i delete libkakao-ios-sdk-i386-armv7-armv7s.a from build phases tab and add to other linker flags. use to -force_load

Comment: Build Settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags  / but it'll make side effect, "file not found: -ObjC" error... -_-a

Comment: My case. When you add .a file in Build Phases > Link Binary, add in the listed .a file on the pop up box. Do not use "Add Other" button. That's it.

Answer (score 29):

Remove the reference to the library and add it again, it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 25):

Use `xcworkspace` it will solve your problem.

I also faced same once I install cocoa pods; Close and launch with `xcworkspace` again will solve your problem.

Comment: simple & works, use `.xcworkspace` file instead of `.xcodeproj`, even for Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you have added the necessary search path for your library in Library Search Paths in Build Settings.

There should be something like:

```
${SOURCE_ROOT}/Framework/Classes
```

For .a files you need to set Target Dependencies in Build Phases in section.
Just click "+" and add your .a file there.

Comment: Target Dependencies in Build Phases in section. there are nothing. Could not select a file.

Comment: Maybe they are using Categories in their library ? For that you should use -ObjC for that file. Hard to say without having a library and chance to play with it.

Comment: I had similar problem. I copied project from other mac machine and in project, there was path of old mac machine from which i copied. So Xcode was trying to get file from older path and was not able to find that file. I changed the path from build settings and it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Had the same problem and none of these answers fix it for me.

Problem was Pod project in workspace had the following config:

```
Build Active Architecture Only: YES
```

For that reason, when I wanted to build for i386 (Simulator), XCode did not build Pods projects, so it could not meet dependencies. As soon as I changed it to `NO` it started working

Comment: Where do I change this setting? Is it a Xcode setting or a line in a Cocoapods config file?

Comment: Click on project name on "Project Navigator" -> Build Settings -> "Build Active Architecture Only". Make sure both your project and "Pods" project have the same settings. Hope that helps

Comment: This would help me, but with opposite way, that I must change from NO to YES. I'm running on 6s simulator, any explanation?

Comment: I think the difference between our situation is other configs, e.g. active architectures. Based on my experience, the project config and the pod project config should be the same. Without having all the info, on my projects and your projects, we could not come to a conclusion. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is here looking specifically for the "library not found for -lPods" error, this was solved by opening the workspace instead of the xcodeproject. Searching google for library not found for -lPods without quotes turns this SO post as the first result, whereas if you wrap the search in quotes you'll get a post with the answer I just gave.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode goto select your project

Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Library Search Paths set the path with **/usr/local/lib**

note : make sure that you have added dylib at frameworks

Answer (score 1):

OS X 10.11 Xcode7.0.1

my case:

```
library not found for -lPods-BlocksKit
error:linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)
```

I delete all pod related content, add "$(inherited)" then fix it.

[Other Linker Flags image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNQiO.jpg)

Comment: you must remove your pods from your  project

Answer (score 0):

my case: use cocoapods, open xcworkspace, and meet "library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking" error.

my solution: Preference -> Location -> Derived Data, click  "Advanced" button -> choose 'shared Folder'.   (when meet error, the original location is Legacy).

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me, so I downloaded the missing library:

https://github.com/danielctull-forks/GoogleAnalytics-SDK-iOS

Answer (score 0):

7.3.1 Pods 1.0.0

Had same stuff today, after cocoapods update from 0.39.0 to 1.0.0.

Had an error : "ld: library not found -lPods".

I've got linked two "Pod" libs, accidentally. One was lPods, and other was lPods-ProjectName. I deleted "libPods.a: from Project>General>Linked Frameworks and Libraries

AND! I changed Pods>Build Active Build Architecture to NO, of course.

And it worked.