# Linker error exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can usually figure out these issues but I just haven't been able to figure this one out, any help?

`Ld /Users/nickporter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/packageTracker-eacmyzjvxkncgxaugoxuxlnmpsgb/Build/Intermediates/packageTracker.build/Debug-iphoneos/packageTracker.build/Objects-normal/armv7/packageTracker normal armv7
    cd /Users/nickporter/Developer/packageTracker
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/nickporter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/packageTracker-eacmyzjvxkncgxaugoxuxlnmpsgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/nickporter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/packageTracker-eacmyzjvxkncgxaugoxuxlnmpsgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/nickporter/Developer/packageTracker/packageTracker -filelist /Users/nickporter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/packageTracker-eacmyzjvxkncgxaugoxuxlnmpsgb/Build/Intermediates/packageTracker.build/Debug-iphoneos/packageTracker.build/Objects-normal/armv7/packageTracker.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -ObjC -lAFNetworking -lAPTimeZones -lAftership-iOS-SDK -lCSNotificationView -lCTFeedback -lDateTools -lMCSwipeTableViewCell -lMMMaterialDesignSpinner -lMTDates -lNSDate+TimeAgo -lNSTimeZone-CountryCode -lRestKit -lSOCKit -lSVGeocoder -lSVPullToRefresh -lSVPulsingAnnotationView -lSVWebViewController -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -lAFNetworking -lAPTimeZones -lAftership-iOS-SDK -lCSNotificationView -lCTFeedback -lDateTools -lMCSwipeTableViewCell -lMMMaterialDesignSpinner -lMTDates -lNSDate+TimeAgo -lNSTimeZone-CountryCode -lRestKit -lSOCKit -lSVGeocoder -lSVPullToRefresh -lSVPulsingAnnotationView -lSVWebViewController -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Accounts -framework Social -lsqlite3 -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Parse -framework Security -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreData -lPods-packageTracker -framework Bolts -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nickporter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/packageTracker-eacmyzjvxkncgxaugoxuxlnmpsgb/Build/Intermediates/packageTracker.build/Debug-iphoneos/packageTracker.build/Objects-normal/armv7/packageTracker_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nickporter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/packageTracker-eacmyzjvxkncgxaugoxuxlnmpsgb/Build/Intermediates/packageTracker.build/Debug-iphoneos/packageTracker.build/Objects-normal/armv7/packageTracker`

`ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: There's no error in your question.

Comment: What's the exact question, clang is saying I can't find this library.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245133/library-not-found-for